# Error in connecting to AS400 DB2 server JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to the AS400 DB2 database using the JDBC in a java program but I am unable to connect as it is giving a SQLException stating No suitable driver found for ​jdbc:as400://192.168.1.11

Whereas I added No suitable driver found for ​jdbc:as400://192.168.1.11

I added the following libraries to my project: db2jcc_licence_cu.jar, db2jcc4.jar, jt400-6.4.jar.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
public class ReadAllTables {
        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                //Class.forName ("com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver");
                DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver());

                // Enable logging
                // DriverManager.setLogStream(System.err);

                System.out.println("Getting Connection");
                Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection ("​jdbc:as400://ipaddress","username","password");  
                DatabaseMetaData md = c.getMetaData();
                ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
                while (rs.next()) {
                  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));

                }



        }

}
```

This is what the error I am getting:

Getting Connection
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for ​jdbc:as400://192.168.1.11
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at com.test.ReadAllTables.main(ReadAllTables.java:18)

Thanks in advance

Comment: _"No suitable driver found "_ means you don't have the AS/400 JDBC driver jar file on the classpath for your code.

Comment: I have jar files in the classpath but still getting this error.

Comment: _Where_ in the classpath.  If Tomcat needs to set up connection pooling the jar may need to go in Tomcat's jar directory, not your appliation's jar directory.

Comment: I have not created any web application or a project whereas I just wrote a java program to test the connection with the AS400 server db2 database.
I added the jar files in environment variables classpath.

Comment: Please show how you run the program. A lot of ways of running Java programs don't use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Currently I have a project in the eclipse in that project I am running this program independently and added the above mentioned libraries in that project lib folder.
and I'm able to access all the classes available in the libraries in the program but still it is giving me an error.

Comment: 'Running this program independently' - how, exactly are you running this program?  Windows command line, IBM i command line, Eclipse Run As..., Linux command line?  The point is that you might be setting CLASSPATH for one environment (Eclipse) but running the program in another environment; one where CLASSPATH is not correct yet.

Answer (score 6):

You *must* have jt400.jar in your classpath for the AS/400 JDBC driver to work.

Version 7.10 is in Maven or download the latest from https://sourceforge.net/projects/jt400/ or copy it from IFS.  The native CC driver is only used when running locally on the AS/400.

Given your current list of jars it sounds like your CLASSPATH variable is incorrect (or if you use a runnable jar, your Class-Path line in the manifest file is wrong).  If you launch with RUNJVA the mechanism is different.

Comment: I tried by adding the jt400 jar in the classpath but to hasn't worked for me

Comment: You should _only_ have jt400.jar in your classpath.  Remove the other ones listed in the question, as they - if I recall correctly - want to use non-Java code you most likely do not have installed.

Comment: It's very important to have the following command in place (like in the question):
DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver());

Comment: @DenisAbakumov I believe that the latest versions of jt400.jar has the metadata in place for this not being necessary anymore.